# Can't find any man pages in Fedora Docker Image

Tags: docker, fedora, manpage

After installing the man pages via dnf, I still can't find them inside /usr/share/man.

```
docker run --rm -it fedora bash -c "dnf install -y man-pages && ls -lR /usr/share/man"
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 5):

The default configuration for the docker version of fedora disable the installation of documentation.

```
cat /etc/dnf/dnf.conf
```

Check out the last line :

```
[main]
gpgcheck=1
installonly_limit=3
clean_requirements_on_remove=True
best=False
skip_if_unavailable=True
tsflags=nodocs
```

However, it is still possible to change the last line or override it like below command :

```
dnf install -y man-pages --setopt='tsflags='
```

Answer (score 2):

I would liked to contribute as I was looking for the answer and I found the answer,  from the link [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/wsl-2-and-man-pages/11337)
Confirm the below line is **removed** from `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`

```
tsflags=nodocs
```

and remove and **reinstall** the man pages using dnf

```
dnf install man man-pages man-db
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the flag, I was searching for long ...
Once reactivated, if you want to install all man pages you can run this :

```
sudo dnf -y reinstall $(rpm -qads --qf "PACKAGE: %{NAME}\n" | sed -n -E '/PACKAGE: /{s/PACKAGE: // ; h ; b }; /^not installed/ { g; p }' | uniq)
```

It will simply reinstall all packages that have documentation with the man pages installed.